# Live Data Web Application Design

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, database-design, web-applications, concurrency

I'm about to begin designing the architecture of a personal project that has the following characteristics:

1. Essentially a "game" containing several concurrent users based on a sport.
2. Matches in this sport are simulated on a regular basis and their results stored in a database.
3. Users can view the details of a simulated match "live" when it is occurring as well as see results after they have occurred.

I developed a similar web application with a much smaller scope as the previous iteration of this project. In that case, however, I chose to go with SQLite as my DB provider since I also had a redistributable desktop application that could be used to manually simulate matches (and in fact that ran as a standalone simulator outside of the web application). My constraints have now shifted to be only a web application, so I don't have to worry about this additional level of complexity.

My main problem with my previous implementation was handling concurrent requests. I made the mistake of using one database (which was represented by a single file on disk) to power both the simulation aspect (which ran in a separate process on the server) and the web application. Hence, when users were accessing the website concurrently with a live simulation happening, there were all sorts of database access issues since it was getting locked by one process. I fixed this by implementing a cross-process mutex on database operations but this drastically slowed down the performance of the website.

The tools I will be using are:

1. ASP.NET for the web application.
2. SQL Server 2008 R2 for the database... probably with an NHibernate layer for object relational mapping.

My question is, how do I design this so I will achieve optimal efficiency as well as concurrent access? Obviously shifting to an actual DB server from a file will have it's positives, but do I need to have two redundant servers--one for the simulation process and one for the web server process?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine doing both on the same database. Concurrent access is what modern database engines are designed for. Concurrent reads are usually no problem at all; concurrent writes lock the minimum possible amount of data (a table, or even just a number of rows), not the entire database.

A few things you should keep in mind though:

- Use transactions wisely. On the one hand, a transaction is an important tool in making sure your database is always consistent - in short, a transaction either happens completely, or not at all. On the other hand, two concurrent transactions can cause deadlocks, and those buggers can be extremely hard to debug.
- Normalize, and use constraints to protect your data integrity. Enforcing foreign keys can save the day, even though it often leads to more cumbersome administration.
- Minimize the amount of time spent on data access: don't keep connections around when you don't need them, make absolutely sure you're not leaking any connections, don't fetch data you know don't need, do as much data-related processing (especially things that can be solved using joins, subqueries, groupings, views, etc.) in SQL instead of in code

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tips. Have you had any experience with NHibernate? Since > 90% of my data is probably going to be stored through the object mapping, do I need to explicitly worry about these things?

Comment: I don't have much experience with NHibernate, but from what I know, if you keep your NHibernate sessions short-lived, you should be fine. The normalization point has nothing to do with the ORM, so you should do that anyway.